# Postcode sectors from postcode

Tags: php, postal-code

Hi i need to extract to the postcode sector from a full postcode.

See below for to see how i need this to return.

```
User inputs "BA12 3GH"  Script Returns >> "BA12"
User inputs "H2 3NM"  Script Returns >> "H2"
```

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, what you are referring to as the Sector is actually the District. The sector would be everything except the last two characters. - http://www.alliescomputing.com/innovation/glossary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$postcode = 'BA12 3GH';
// If you want both parts, do list($sector, $otherpart) = ...
list($sector) = explode(' ', $postcode);
echo $sector;
```

(you should add  `, 2` in the `explode` if you want to extract both parts, so if the inputs `AA BB CC` then `$otherpart` becomes `BB CC`)

Comment: Bril  i need to go back to school

Answer (score 0):

To make things better, you need to understand the format of a postcode, which consists of outcode and incode. for instance, "BA12 3GH", BA12 is the outcode and 3GH is incode. The outcode can be 2-4 chars, such as B1, EH16. However, the incode always is three chars, starts with a digit, and followed with two chars. For more information about the format rules: http://www.ukpostcode.net/uk-postcodes-formatting-rules-wiki-6.html

Thus, it will become very clear.

$sector = trim(substr($postcode,0,-3));

Scripts above will also work when user input postcode without space between outcode and incode.